# Which transcript to submit to job?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, career-development

I will soon be graduating with my master's degree; I also completed my undergraduate degree at the same institution.

As I've been applying for jobs, several companies have asked for a copy of my transcripts. Is it wrong to only submit my graduate transcript? My graduate GPA is very good (4.00/4.00), while my undergraduate GPA is much lower.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked those companies (recruiters and HR) via emails or phone calls ?

Comment: Is your graduate degree in the same field as your undergraduate? In other words, did you receive an undergraduate in "Under Water Basket Weaving," and are you currently working on your Master's in "Under Water Basket Weaving"? How do the two degrees correlate.

Answer (score 6):

> As I've been applying for jobs, several companies have asked for a
> copy of my transcripts. Is it wrong to only submit my graduate
> transcript?

If you actually want the job, it's wrong not to give them whatever they are asking for.

If a potential employer asks for a copy of your "transcripts" you can be sure they want to see all of them, not just the ones you prefer.

Besides, lower undergraduate scores followed by excellent graduate scores could mean growth and maturity. Nothing to hide.

Comment: I would add that if you've completed a graduate degree, employers will be less likely to look at your undergraduate performance with much detail. Not including it is very obvious that you're trying to hide something.